# Help identify this cabinet clip used to mount face frame on cabinet?

Tags: cabinets, hardware, custom-cabinetry

This clip is used to mount a frame around a built-in oven. Some of the clips have broken and I'd love to replace them. The metal piece goes on the frame, with the plastic piece on the cabinet. A corse screw goes through the plastic piece and into the metal piece on the frame.

Any ideas on what these are called or where I can find some replacements? Ideally would be able to find the exact replacements so I don't need to re-measure and align everything again.

[image: This is a clip which is used to put a face frame on a cabinet]

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, those were harder to find than expected. It's extremely unlikely that you'll find an exact match (unless you can go back to the manufacturer of your cabinets), but here's a few possibilities.

Hettich: https://diy.hettich.com/en/products/connecting-fittings/carcase-and-cabinets-connectors.html

Blum: http://www.wwhardware.com/blum-surface-mount-rta-fittings-b040-2

Lee Valley: http://www.leevalley.com/en/hardware/page.aspx?p=40080&cat=3,41306,41319&ap=1 (Although these don't look like much, they're extremely solid and set with a satisfying thunk. They'll also come apart without wrecking anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Given that multiples of these have already broken, I would recommend NOT replacing them with the same type of hardware. It is obviously too weak for the intended use.

I would recommend these as a possible alternative:
[Keku Clips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027Z7T64)
[image: Keku Clips]